# How can I improve and speak English fluently?

Tags: british-english

English is not my first language and I am very bad in English. But I want to learn English so I could speak in English. It's my dream to learn English. But I do not have money to attend English classes. Could you guys please guide me to how can I speak English fluently?

Comment: English is no different from any other language.  How would you answer, if someone asked how to become fluent in your own native tongue?  Study hard, read as much as you can, watch movies and television in that language, talk to native speakers (online if you can't meet them in person), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Learning English is just the same as learning any other language, like you have learned your native language.

You could try:

- Learning English from some apps or textbooks
- Watching TV in that language and films and reading books help to understand new words
- Try speak to fluent speakers of that language and talk to them

Remember practicing speaking it in real life is the best way. You will learn new words, recognise your mistakes and practice grammar and sentence construction.